# how to pass wild card arguments to perl script in snakefile?

Tags: perl, snakemake

I try to write a rule in a Snakefile that is able to run a custom perl script. There are two input files and one output file. The inputfile and outputfile have wildcards in them because I want to run the script for various files. But when I expand in order to generate the different input and output files, the perl script takes ALL the possible input files as input while I would like them to go one by one. What should I do to make perl 'eat' the input files one by one? This is my code:

```
DOMAINS= ["Metallophos", "PP2C", "Y_phosphatase"]
SUPERGROUPS=["2supergroups","5supergroups"]

rule add_supergroups:
    input:
        newick=expand("data/{domain}/{supergroup}/RAxML_bipartitionsBranchLabels.bbhlist.txt.{domain}.fa.aligned.rp.me-25.id.phylip",domain=DOMAINS, supergroup=SUPERGROUPS),
        sup="data/species.v3.1.1.supergroups.txt"
    output:
        expand("results/{domain}/{supergroup}/RAxML_bipartitionsBranchLabels.bbhlist.txt.{domain}.fa.aligned.rp.me-25.id.phylip.supergroups", domain=DOMAINS, supergroup=SUPERGROUPS)
    shell:
        "perl scripts/change_newick.pl {input.sup} {input.newick} {output}"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can remove the expand() function and use rule "all" to define your target. The value of the wildcards in rule add_supergroups will automatically be inferred from this target file.

You could even use different names for the wildcards in rule "add_supergroups" for Snakemake would recognize and match the patterns.

```
DOMAINS= ["Metallophos", "PP2C", "Y_phosphatase"]
SUPERGROUPS=["2supergroups","5supergroups"]

rule all: 
    input: expand("results/{domain}/{supergroup}/RAxML_bipartitionsBranchLabels.bbhlist.txt.{domain}.fa.aligned.rp.me-25.id.phylip.supergroups"

rule add_supergroups:
    input:
        newick="data/{domain}/{supergroup}/RAxML_bipartitionsBranchLabels.bbhlist.txt.{domain}.fa.aligned.rp.me-25.id.phylip",
        sup="data/species.v3.1.1.supergroups.txt"
    output:
        "results/{domain}/{supergroup}/RAxML_bipartitionsBranchLabels.bbhlist.txt.{domain}.fa.aligned.rp.me-25.id.phylip.supergroups"
    shell:
        "perl scripts/change_newick.pl {input.sup} {input.newick} {output}"
```

Theoretically, it should even work like this:

```
DOMAINS= ["Metallophos", "PP2C", "Y_phosphatase"]
SUPERGROUPS=["2supergroups","5supergroups"]

rule all: 
    input: expand("results/{domain}/{supergroup}/RAxML_bipartitionsBranchLabels.bbhlist.txt.{domain}.fa.aligned.rp.me-25.id.phylip.supergroups"

rule add_supergroups:
    input:
        newick="data/{foo}",
        sup="data/species.v3.1.1.supergroups.txt"
    output:
        "results/{foo}.supergroups"
    shell:
        "perl scripts/change_newick.pl {input.sup} {input.newick} {output}"
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your rule wants​ to run all of your files is simple : the function **expand()**.

Like you seem to know, expand makes​ a list of python strings​ very useful for managing files in Snakemake.

But in your​ example, the rule wants​ to run the perl script with a **list of files** in `{input.newick}` and one file in `{input.sup}` to produce a list of files as your output.

You can easely resolve your problem by not using the `expand function on the input and output`.

But how will Snakemake recognize that he has to produce all the files? 
By creating a **rule target before** your `rule add_supergroups` which will take as input the expand of your `rule add_supergroups`.

Let's do some code :

```
DOMAINS= ["Metallophos", "PP2C", "Y_phosphatase"]
SUPERGROUPS=["2supergroups","5supergroups"]

rule target :
  input :
    expand("results/{domain}/{supergroup}/RAxML_bipartitionsBranchLabels.bbhlist.txt.{domain}.fa.aligned.rp.me-25.id.phylip.supergroups", 
           domain=DOMAINS,
           supergroup=SUPERGROUPS)

rule add_supergroups:
    input:
        newick="data/{domain}/{supergroup}/RAxML_bipartitionsBranchLabels.bbhlist.txt.{domain}.fa.aligned.rp.me-25.id.phylip",
        sup="data/species.v3.1.1.supergroups.txt"
    output:
        "results/{domain}/{supergroup}/RAxML_bipartitionsBranchLabels.bbhlist.txt.{domain}.fa.aligned.rp.me-25.id.phylip.supergroups"
    shell:
        "perl scripts/change_newick.pl {input.sup} {input.newick} {output}"
```

Now it should work. Snakemake need a list of files for the `target rule`. He search into all the rules to find if one can produce these files.

In this case, he recognize the `pattern filename` of `output add_supergroups`. So he will complete the **wilcards** by DOMAINS and SUPERGROUPS automatically. The rule `add_supergroups` will be run one by one file.

Comment: Hehe, you were faster than me obviously ;-)

Comment: I like that there are two good answers by two new users. Keep it up. :-)

Comment: We happen to be both part of the French "Snakemake community" :)